# Placing an ImageView below a TextView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I have a `RelativeLayout` with a `TextView` and an `ImageView` that looks like this:

[image]

The orange is the `ImageView`'s background color to illustrate how much space is between the start of the image itself and the start of the `ImageView`. How can I make my image display at the top of my `ImageView` so that the title is directly above the image without the orange in between?

This is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Recyclerview -->
    <com.sometimestwo.moxie.MultiClickRecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_zoomie_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- Container for title and image-->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/hover_view_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center|top"
        android:visibility="gone">

      <!-- Title -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/hover_view_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorBgBlackTint"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
            android:visibility="visible" />

     <!-- Imageview that holds dog picture -->
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/hover_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/hover_view_title"
            android:background="@color/colorDarkThemeAccent"
            android:visibility="visible" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: why you use the relative layout? why not use linear layout? or constraint layout? although you can achieve I'll write an answer for you for image and source code

Comment: try to add `adjustViewBound: true` on the `<ImageView>` in xml layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can achieve that using **`RelativeLayout`** in that way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="216dp"
        android:layout_height="217dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

here is a screenshot of my result

[image]

also, by **`LinearLayout`** in this way :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="216dp"
        android:layout_height="217dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several options here, I would really recommend using a ConstraintLayout, but that's really another issue. To make your layout work as expected I would suggest adding `scaleType="fit_start"`. This will scale the image so that it fits in your ImageView and align it to the top/left (right in an rtl layout). Settings `adjustViewBounds="true"` will most likely also work, unless you need the image to be that tall in all cases.